# What does "X += nb; Y+= nb;" mean if X and Y are two vectors and nb is an integer?

Tags: vector, integer, pseudocode

at page 8 of the paper :
  [Reducing floating point error in dot product using the superblock family of algorithms- Anthony M. Castaldo , R.Clint Whaley, and Anthony T. Chronopouos][1]

there is the following code:

```
typedef double scalar;
typedef scalar *Vec;
scalar dotProd(Vec X, Vec Y, int nb)
{  int n = X.length;
   int nblks = n / nb;
   int nsblks = sqrt(nblks);
   int blksInSblk = nblks / nsblks;
   scalar dot = 0.0, sdot, cdot;

   for (s=0; s < nsblks; s++)
   {  sdot = 0.0;
      for (b=0; b < blksInSblk; b++)
      {
         cdot = X[0] * Y[0];
         for (i=1; i < nb; i++)
            cdot += X[i] * Y[i];
         sdot += cdot;
         X += nb; Y += nb;
      }
      dot += sdot;
   }
   return dot;
}
```

I do not understand this line of the pseudocode:

```
X += nb; Y+= nb;
```

What does it mean if `X` and `Y` are two vectors and `nb` is an integer?

**Addendum**: if not using pointers, how to "increment" by `nb` elements?

```
int n = x.size();
int nblks = n / nb;

int nsblks = sqrt(nblks);
int blksInSblk = nblks / nsblks;
double dot = 0.0;
double sdot = 0.0;
double cdot = 0.0;
for(int s=0;s<nsblks;s++) {
  std::cout << "iteration s= " << s << std::endl;
  for(int b=0;b<blksInSblk;b++) {
    std::cout << "iteration b= " << b << std::endl;
    cdot += x(0) * y(0);
    std::cout << "cdot += x(0) * y(0) = " << cdot << std::endl;
       int pointingTo = 0;
      for(int i=pointingTo;i<nb;i++) {
        cdot += x(i) * y(i);
      }
      sdot += cdot;
      // Increment the pointer to x by nb elements:
      // x += nb;
      pointingTo += nb;
      // Increment the pointer to y by nb elements;
      // y += nb
    //}
  }
  dot += sdot;
}
```

Comment: It means to increment the pointer to `X` by `nb` elements.

Comment: With the appropriate typedefs, this could almost be C code, more than just pseudo code.

Comment: Thank you Mad Physicist. I actually didn't know that += applied to a vector means incrementing the pointer to X by rhs_value elements

Comment: Mad Physicist, one more question: if X += nb means incrementing the pointer to X by nb elements, if I do not use any pointer, do you think that inserting the increment within the inner cycle give the same result?  :  for(int s=0;s<nsblks;s++) {  for(int b=0;b<blksInSblk;b++) { cdot += x(0) * y(0); int pointingTo = 0; for(int i=pointingTo;i<nb;i++) { cdot += x(i) * y(i); } sdot += cdot; pointingTo += nb; } dot += sdot; }

Comment: Would you mind posting that as an addendum to your question ? I'll write up an answer for you to accept if this really helps you.

Comment: Also , could you replace the original image with the equivalent text in the question please ?

Comment: I posted my "solution" without pointers for incrementing by nb... is it correct?

Comment: You forgot to include the function signature...

Comment: Your "copy" of the original pseudo-code was incredibly sloppy. I went ahead and fixed it up. Please complete your addendum example to show the input types.

Comment: My answer shows you how to run the original in C. You should be able to print out the intermediate results and compare against your proposed solution pretty easily without my help.

Comment: Thank a lot Mad Physicist for your kind help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show can be interpreted as C code if you assume

```
typedef double scalar;
typedef scalar *Vec;
```

and add a line like `int s, b, i;` somewhere before your first loop.

In that case, it is pretty clear that `X += nb` is incrementing the pointer to `X` by the size of `nb` scalars. This is consistent with what the algorighm seems to be doing: summing up the dot product in chunks of size `nb` instead of all at once.